# How can I create a vector of means of a function applied to a set of data?

Tags: r

Sorry for the poorly worded title, I tried to keep it short. Here is my problem: I simulated ten thousand values from a distribution. For t being integers ranging from 0 to twenty, I want to apply a function of t to the data. Then for each t, I want the means of the new data sets in a single vector. I have my function, I just am having trouble iterating it to create many new data vectors and getting the means in a single vector. I don't want to go through the process twenty times. Thank you!

```
Tx <- (x1, x2, ..., xn)
fcn <- function(t){ifelse(t < Tx & Tx <20, 10000*exp(-.05*(Tx.min20 - t)), ifelse(Tx < t, NA, 0))}
t <- (0:20)
```

This is what I have. I can run my code and get individual vectors like

```
fcn.0 = (fcn.0(x1), fcn.0(x2), ..., fcn.0(xn))
    ...
    fcn.20 = (fcn.20(x1), fcn.20(x2), ... , fcn.20(xn))
```

I want to be able to create them all at once, then get something like

```
mean.vec = (mean(fcn.0), mean(fcn.1, ..., mean(fcn.20))
```

Comment: Please edit your question to add sample data,code,current and expected output.

Comment: You might want to check `library(zoo)` and `rollmean()` or `rollapply()` for custom functions. Maybe something like: `rollapply(data = 1:100, width = 20, FUN = mean, by = 20)`